# How to break a string, that was read using fgets(), using scanf("%s",..)

Tags: c, buffer, scanf, fgets

I am working on a program that takes a mathematical expression, transforms it to posfix notation and then solves it.

First I am checking the expression to see if it is well formed ( Open brackets and parenthesis matches the closing ones ). To do the part of checking I used `fgets()` to get the string, because it ignores white spaces as far as I know.

Now I have to break the string when a white space shows up, but for this part would be easier to use a *do while* using the buffer of a `scanf( "%s" ,...)`

Is there any way that I can use the scanf trick to break the string, work on int part by part without reading it again?

Comment: Take a look at fame open, you can use it to convert a string into a stream.  Take a look at https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/String-Streams.html

Comment: you can use `strtok`

Comment: Thanks for the replies, both streams and strtok will help me for sure. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sscanf()` to advance through a buffer read by `fgets()`
%n will receive the number of characters used by the scan.  Adding used to the offset will advance the scan through the buffer.

```
int offset = 0;
int used = 0;
char line[1000];
char item[200];
fgets ( line, sizeof ( line), stdin);
while ( ( sscanf ( line + offset, "%199s%n", item, &used)) == 1) {
    offset += used;
    // do something with item
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a buffer to store all the data that is read at the first time using the fgets(); function.

So if the expression is well formed you already have the data, and do not need to read it

The algorithm would be:
     Use the fgets() to get each part of the expression
     Store in a buffer variable separating then using a space or another character
    If the expression is well formed, get the buffer
     Read each part of the buffer that is separated with space and put then in a new int variable (or array)
   Compute the expression using this variables (or array)

look this 2 function, they may help you

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/